# C# Manual mapping from Autmatically created respositoryModel(from db) to custom view model

Tags: c#

I have been using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) which I find really good. 
But in current project I can't use AutoMapper because few reasons. lets not go into that.

Wondering if below is best way of manual mapping? Seems like it will be lot of looping depending on complexity of the model and one to many relationship.

Is there best or efficient way of doing manual mapping.

```
Basket basket = StoreRepository.GetBasket(BasketCode); // where BasketCode is xyz

List<ProductResponse> basketProducts = new List<ProductResponse>();
foreach (Product product in basket.Products) {

    basketProducts.Add(new ProductResponse()
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Description = product.Description
         });
}

BasketResponse result = new BasketResponse()
{
     BasketCode = basket.Code,
     Description = basket.Description,                
     IntroMessage = basket.IntroMessage,
     Products = basketProducts 
};

return result;
```

Above is snippet from a method of Web API Controller which return Json. 
I am using manual mapping to reduce detailed complexity and create required Json structure and data.

Answer (score 0):

May be this question should be in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyway you can simplify your code by using `Select` `LINQ` query instead of `FOREACH` loop to build `basketProducts` list, like below.

```
List<ProductResponse> basketProducts = basket.Products.Select(product=> new ProductResponse()
{
   Name = product.Name,
   Description = product.Description
 }).ToList();
```

You can simplify this further by writing a new delegate for mapping which can be reused at multiple places.

```
Func<Product, ProductResponse> MapProduct = delegate (Product product)
        {
            return new ProductResponse()
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Description = product.Description
            };
        };
```

then your code will be much simpler like below. Use the new delegate in `SELECT` method of `LINQ` query.

```
Basket basket = StoreRepository.GetBasket(BasketCode); 

BasketResponse result = new BasketResponse()
{
    BasketCode = basket.Code,
    Description = basket.Description,
    IntroMessage = basket.IntroMessage,
    Products = basket.Products.Select(MapProduct).ToList()
};
return result;
```

Comment: True, I should have created it under https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, Not sure, if questions are transferable after they are created?

Comment: i don't think you can move the question, but next time you can create similar questions in code review if your code is working but not sure if it's good code :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off creating some kind of general function for each class so you don't have to repeat the mapping everytime you want to use it. For example:

```
public static class Mapper
{   
    public static ProductResponse Map(Product product)
    {
        return new ProductResponse
                   {
                      Name = product.Name,
                      Description = product.Description
                   };
    }

    public static BasketResponse Map(Basket basket)
    {
        return new BasketResponse
                   {
                       BasketCode = basket.Code,
                       Description = basket.Description,                
                       IntroMessage = basket.IntroMessage,
                       Products = basket.Products.Select(a => Mapper.Map(a))
                   };
    }
}
```